# UML for system modelling or for software modelling?

Tags: uml

Is UML (unified modelling language) a technique for system modelling or for software modelling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both. Some diagrams are more useful for software modeling, but some others can be used for both. A state machine for example can be used for a software or a system.

But if you want to model a system with UML, you should take a look at [SysML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_Modeling_Language) a profile to specialize your UML models.

Comment: Thank you@Xaelis very much for your responsible answers in "UML" tag
 and this one as well 
if possible ,I wonder if there is link to an example shows a state machine for a software and for a system?

Comment: There is a lot of examples, try to search 'UML state machine' on google images.

Answer (score 3):

UML is a general purpose modeling language, although it's primarily geared toward modeling object-oriented software systems. The latest version of the UML specification contains 14 diagrams, some of which are applicable to software in general while others make more sense when applied to modeling object-oriented software systems. Seven UML diagrams are used in SysML, which is commonly used for systems and systems-of-systems modeling.

Answer (score 2):

UML is a tool for modeling all kinds of things, not even just programming related.  For example, you can use state diagrams to model the function of a control panel, e.g. a thermostat.  You can use use-case diagrams or sequence diagrams to document business processes.

You can use activity diagrams to show how a hamburger is made in a fast-food restaurant.

Comment: @user2019510, glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

According to the wikipedia article about [Unified Modeling Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) it is "a standardized (ISO/IEC 19501:2005), general-purpose modeling language in the field of software engineering. The Unified Modeling Language includes a set of graphic notation techniques to create visual models of object-oriented software-intensive systems."

It is used to describe the more abstract structure of the system and the software itself at the same time.

If you take a look at the article (which I highly recommend), you'll notice that

```
"The Unified Modeling Language (UML) offers a standard way to visualize a system's     architectural blueprints, including elements such as:
* activities
* actors
* business processes
* database schemas
* (logical) components
* programming language statements"
* reusable software components"
```

By describing the activities, actors, business processes you basically describe the abstract representation/design of the system.
And by describing the (logical) components, programming language statements, reusable software components you describe the implementation details (software).